# Java - Another "BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray always null"

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, decode

I have an image stored in the database in this form

```
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2w <...> igD//2Q=="
```

so definitely base64 encoded.

I get it via a php function:

```
...
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `Data` FROM `UserPicture` WHERE `UserId` = ?");

$query->bind_param('i', $id);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($data);
$query->fetch();

echo base64_encode($data);
```

Android gets it via a call:

```
StringBuffer result = m_dbi.getResult(Constants.SERVER_HOST_PHP + "/get_user_picture.php", params, "GET");
```

Debugging I've seen that *result* is correct.

I pass *result.toString()* to a writeImageToFile(String pic) that does:

```
...
byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(pic, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
...
```

*pic* is correct as well as *decodedByte.length* but ***bm*** **is always null**.

I've tried to change *Base64.DEFAULT* to *NO_PADDING* or *NO_WRAP* but always null.

What could be the reason ?

Comment: When you wrote the `byte[]` out to a file, and attempted to view it in an image viewer on your development machine, what did you learn?

Comment: If it is saved in the database in base64, why are you calling `base64_encode` on it?

Comment: @CommonsWare: whar should I learn ? it's just an unreadable picture.

Comment: @RealSkeptic:  right, my fault. I save it to the database decoded ($pic_buff = base64_decode($base);    $pic_buff = $db->real_escape_string($pic_buff);) so I have to encode it when fetching it.

Comment: You are saving it to disk after running a function that expects a string on it? What type is your db column, and what database?

Comment: mysql - the column is BLOB(500000) and yes, I fetch it, save it to disk and pass the filename to other activities. The design is still on work, the problem is that the engine doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: You should *not* be escaping a blob. [Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/php_s_mysqli_extension_storing) is how Oracle says a blob should be saved. Escaping means that some of the bytes change before saving, and that may render the image invalid.

Comment: Yep, this was definitely the problem, thanks. It has been working escaping till I moved to php parameters (prepare query, etc). If you create an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused because you saved the images in a BLOB using `mysqli`'s `real_escape_string()`. This method, like any string-escaping method, is intended for text, and changes content it perceives as invalid characters. Applying this to an image rather than a string corrupted the image.

A BLOB should be stored using the procedure described in [this Oracle blog entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/php_s_mysqli_extension_storing), using `send_long_data()` and no escaping.

Comment: Ok solved, thanks.  The strange thing is that real_escape_string() was working before I moved to prepare() and send_long_data(). Your answer helped me fixing also the INSERT/SELECT of the PDFs so I should accept it twice :-)